Create autoinstaller for Lubuntu doesn't work
am trying to create an autoinstaller for Lubuntu iso. i have created the below files:

xfile.preseed
adjusted the grub.cfg file accordingly .

here is my preseed file:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Localization
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us

# Network configuration
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# Mirror settings
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy string

# Account setup
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/root-password password <root_password>
d-i passwd/root-password-again password <root_password>

# Clock and time zone setup
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string UTC

# Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman/default_filesystem string ext4
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
    boot-root :: \
        512 512 512 ext4 \
            $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
            method{ format } format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ /boot } \
        . \
        100% 512 100% ext4 \
            method{ format } format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ / } \
        .

# Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect lubuntu-desktop

# Boot loader installation
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

# Finish installation without user interaction
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

# Preseed late command
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    in-target wget -O /tmp/autoinstall.sh http://path/to/your/autoinstall.sh; \
    in-target chmod +x /tmp/autoinstall.sh; \
    in-target /bin/bash /tmp/autoinstall.sh

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

here is my grub.cfg command:
menuentry "Install Lubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ounch.preseed auto=true priority=critical debian-installer/locale=en_US keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us ubiquity/reboot=casper languagechooser/language-name=English countrychooser/shortlist=US localechooser/supported-locales=en_US.UTF-8 boot=casper automatic-ubiquity quiet splash noprompt noshell ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
}

and i extracted the Lubuntu iso image using CUBIC and modified the above files. After that i have packed the iso image using CUBIC and i tried to run the image using VM. The problem is: the iso is ignoring the auto-installer and straightaway bring me to lubuntu live window. Can anyone help me with this? appreciate your kind help and support.

@guiverc - I have created a yaml file to be used as preseed here is the content of the new yaml file:
localization:
  locale: en_US
  consoleSetup:
    askDetect: false
  keyboardConfiguration:
    layoutCode: us

# Network configuration
networking:
  interfaceSelection: auto

# Mirror settings
mirror:
  country: manual
  http:
    hostname: archive.ubuntu.com
    directory: /ubuntu
    proxy: ""

# Account setup
users:
  root:
    login: true
    password: "<root_password>"
    passwordRepeat: "<root_password>"

# Clock and time zone setup
timezone:
  utc: true
  zone: UTC

# Partitioning
partitions:
  method: regular
  recipe: atomic
  defaultFilesystem: ext4
  expertRecipe: |
    boot-root :: \
        512 512 512 ext4 \
            $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
            method{ format } format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ /boot } \
        . \
        100% 512 100% ext4 \
            method{ format } format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ / } \
        .

# Package selection
packages:
  lubuntu-desktop:
    selected: true

# Boot loader installation
bootloader:
  installer: true
  debian: true
  otherOs: true

# Finish installation without user interaction
finish:
  rebootInProcess: note

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
And i have updated the grub.cfg config to:
menuentry "Install Lubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper  file=/cdrom/preseed/ounch.yaml auto=true priority=critical quiet splash noprompt noshell ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
}

Still the problem persist. The system is ignoring my preconfig files.

You've not provided any release details; but Lubuntu uses the calamares installer, and you appear to be creating a seed file for a different installer (thus your file being ignored is to be expected!)  (ubiquity and debian-installer were last used by Lubuntu with the 18.04 release)

@guiverc thanks for your prompt response. the iso image that am using is:
lubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
so, you mean that i need to create a seed file for calamares ?

Currently you've created a preseed file for an 18.04 ISO (using ubiquity or debian-installer  (scan thru your pasted data; there is no d-i or ubiquity (inc. maybe-ubiquity) on 18.10 & later ISOs of Lubuntu)

Does this answer your question? Unattended install for Lubuntu
